# How copy mains file to specific folder with Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

My .bowerrc is like this:

```
{
  "directory": "components",
  "strict-ssl": true
}
```

In bower.json I have:

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "~2.1.1",
  "bootstrap": "~3.3.1"
}
```

When I run **bower install**, it downloads the **jquery** and **bootstrap** to **components** folder.

I'm trying using Grunt to generate a structure like below, but, I'm not find a plugin that do the this.

```
build /
      js/jquery.min.js
      js/bootstrap.min.js
      css/bootstrap.min.css
      fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
      fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
      fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
      fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

After copy these files, I want to zip (I know how to do this step) the content inside build folder.

Comment: You can also use `grunt-contrib-concat` to combine the files to reduce network requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [grunt-bower-taks](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task) to achieve this. This task will take care of downloading the files using bower and placing them in the structure you require.
You will need to specify a custom layout that will match the folder structure you require. This is done by adding a custom layout function as part of the task options:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    bower: {
      install: {
        options: {
            targetDir: "./build",
            verbose: true,
            layout: function(type, component, source) {
              return type;
            }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-task');
};
```

Since you want want more than "main" files, you will also need to add an `exportsOverride` section into your bower.json:

```
"exportsOverride": {
    "jquery": {
      "js": "dist/*.js"
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      "js": "dist/js/*.js",
      "css" : "dist/css/*.css",
      "fonts" : "dist/fonts/*.*"
    }
  }
```